# Iterating over unique values for auditing purposes?

Tags: python, pandas

Say we have a list of unique categories in dataframe df2:

```
categories = df2['Category'].unique()
```

I want to loop through each category in df2, match it to the variable categories above, and apply a lambda function. What would the syntax be?

I have tried the following:

```
df2.loc[df2.Category == categories, :].apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=3) if 
x.size*0.01 < 3 else x.sample(frac=0.01))
```

presumably, the code above should loop through each category in categories and bring back all items in that category, right? Or am I missing something? The error I get is as follows:

```
ValueError: Lengths must match to compare.
```

The error I'm getting, I think, is because df.Category is longer than categories because df.Category is a list of all categories, which are duplicates, which is why I tried .unique(). Is there a way to remedy this issue so my code works? Thank you for your time.

Comment: `df2['Category'].unique()` is a list you probably need to use `isin` but in theory every value in `df2['Category]` would return True...

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I'm trying to take a sample from every category in the dataframe, not the dataframe as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I suggest:

```py
# I reproduce the dataset
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Category": np.arange(0, 20).repeat(5),
                   "value": np.random.random(20*5)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Category": np.arange(20, 40).repeat(500),
                   "value": np.random.random(20*500)})
df = pd.concat([df1,df2]) # I concat these two to get varying category sizes


df2 = (df.groupby("Category").apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=3) if x.size*0.01 < 3 
                                                            else x.sample(frac=0.01))
                             .drop(columns="Category"))
```

You see that you get a multiindex with Category and the indexes of observations in the sample for each category. You have sample of 3 for category going from 0 to 19 and a sample of 5 for above categories.

```
               value
Category            
0        1  0.286139
         4  0.719469
         2  0.226851
1        9  0.392118
         7  0.684830
```